# Electron import x509 cert to local keychain (macOS) - The authorization was denied since no user interaction was possible

Tags: node.js, macos, security, electron, x509certificate

I'd like to import a cert (x509) to local keystore (win and macOS). With this electron app user can create a website locally and can enable HTTPS that's why we need to store the cert.

#### The issue:

In some rare cases the user get an error message during cert import **only on macOS**:

> Command failed: security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k
> /Library/Keychains/System.keychain /Users/user/ssl/asdasd.local.crt
> SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings: The authorization was denied since
> no user interaction was possible.

If the user run the exact same command with `sudo` in terminal it works as expected.

*Note: All users who get this error message has enabled apple watch authentication, but we know a user who has also enabled apple watch auth end he didn't get error message.*

#### What we do:

In electron renderer process we run the following commands with [sudo-prompt](https://github.com/jorangreef/sudo-prompt) npm package. Every time first we delete the cert from keystore if it does exist and add the new one.

**Windows add cert:**

```sh
certutil -addstore -f ROOT C:\Users\user\ssl\asdasd.local.crt
```

**Windows delete cert:**

```sh
certutil -delstore ROOT asdasd.local
```

**macOS add cert:**

```sh
security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain /Users/user/ssl/asdasd.local.crt
```

**macOS delete cert:**

```sh
security delete-certificate -c asdasd.local
```

#### UPDATE

I've opened an issue in `sudo-prompt` repo: https://github.com/jorangreef/sudo-prompt/issues/137

M1 mac asks password twice.

#### UPDATE 2

I've just realized this issue does not related to M1. Maybe related to Big Sur 11.1.

It looks like `sudo-prompt` package hides the second password dialog.

#### UPDATE 3

The command stores the cert in keychain but the trust value is not "Always trust" if the error occurs.

#### UPDATE 4

I've tried `osascript` way. It works perfectly on Big Sur 11.0, but It gave the same error on M1 Big Sur 11.1. (screenshot attached)[image]

#### How am I trying to test?

running the following command:

```js
const sudo = require('sudo-prompt')

sudo.exec(
  'security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain /Users/kotapeter/ssl/test.local.crt',
  {
    name: 'test',
  },
  (error, stdout) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      console.log(stdout)
    }
  }
)
```

We use the following cert format: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest use a approach like below which will automatically ask for Admin access via GUI

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const proc = exec('osascript -e \'do shell script "pwd" with administrator privileges\'', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error.stack);
      console.log('Error code: '+error.code);
      console.log('Signal received: '+error.signal);
    }
    console.log('Child Process STDOUT: '+stdout);
    console.log('Child Process STDERR: '+stderr);
  });
  
  proc.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('Child process exited with exit code '+code);
  });
```

[image: Admin access]

[image: Output]

This is on **MacOS Big Sur 11.1**

Update **23-Jan-21**:

You can build your own executable and run it from NodeJS

```swift
//
//  main.swift
//  AddCert
//
//  Created by Tarun Lalwani on 23/01/21.
//

import Foundation

import Security

let certInfo: CFDictionary

enum SecurityError:Error {
    case generalError
}

func deleteCertificateFromKeyChain(_ certificateLabel:String) -> Bool{
    
    let delQuery : [NSString:Any] = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassCertificate,
        kSecAttrLabel: certificateLabel,
    ]
    let delStatus:OSStatus = SecItemDelete(delQuery as CFDictionary)
    
    return delStatus == errSecSuccess
    
}

func saveCertificateToKeyChain(_ certificate:SecCertificate, certificateLabel:String) throws {
    deleteCertificateFromKeyChain(certificateLabel)

    let setQuery: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassCertificate,
        kSecValueRef: certificate,
        kSecAttrLabel: certificateLabel as AnyObject,
        kSecAttrAccessible: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
    ]
    let addStatus:OSStatus = SecItemAdd(setQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
    
    
    guard addStatus == errSecSuccess else {
        throw SecurityError.generalError
    }
    
    var status = SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings(certificate, SecTrustSettingsDomain.admin, nil)
    
}

func getCertificateFromString(stringData:String) throws -> SecCertificate{
    
    if let data:NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: stringData, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)  {
        if let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, data) {
            return certificate
        }
    }
    throw SecurityError.generalError
}

var certificateString:String = "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"


let certificate = try! getCertificateFromString(stringData: certificateString)


try? saveCertificateToKeyChain(certificate, certificateLabel: "Test")
```

In above example, I didn't use a certificate file, but you can update the code to use that and you can also use command line arguments to take a filepath

Credits to below file for getting this code working

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-swift-security/blob/c26988a7f5de338c1d9e0d43a64c2b6db33be541/Source/mca/internal/certificate/SecurityUtils.swift

Comment: Thank you! It looked really promising. I tried what you suggest but unfortunately I gave the same error. The first dialog came up, I've entered my password and I see the error in the terminal. Did you try the command which I mentioned in the post? 
(question has updated)

Comment: Sorry but I don't have a M1 with me.

Comment: and is this cert import script running on your computer without error? I think the cause of the problem is Big Sur 11.1 and not M1. If I just import a cert via command line I get password prompt twice. On Big Sur 11.0 I get this prompt only once.

Comment: Let me verify that

Comment: Please join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227411/electron-import-x509-cert-to-local-keychain-macos-the-authorization-was-denie

Comment: Tarun, Apple has just answered to me. Do you have idea how can we use SecItem from terminal? https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671582

Comment: @PeterKota, check the update, build it and execute the executable via process

Comment: Thank you so much  I haven't had time for testing/trying out this but looks really promising!

Comment: This does not see to work (any more?). The certificate get installed, but it does not appear as trusted.